# Google App Engine Model Parents

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, model

I am somewhat new to the google app engine models system(and all database models for that matter), and I am trying to figure out how make a model have a collection of model instances as one of the properties. Some how I feel that there has to be a better way to model the data I have.

So here is the example. I'm writing a journal webapp. I want to allow users to have multible journals as defined by the model `Journals`

```
#Represents a collection of journals
class Journals(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    journals = db.ListProperty(int)  #there has to be a better way of keeping track of journals then by a list of their id
```

In the property `journals` I keep a list of the id's of the `Journal` model(shown below).

```
class Journal(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    journal_item = db.ListProperty(int)
```

In the Journal model I store a list of id's of `JournalItem` instances as a list of id's

```
class JournalItem(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

So I guess the question really is how should I model data with this structure(I omitted some properties to simplify it)(shown in json).

```
"Journals": {
    "Journal": {
        "user": "GAE user object",
        "name": "journal 1",
        "JournalItems": {
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry 1",
                "content": "some example content"
            },
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry 2",
                "content": "some example content"
            },
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry n",
                "content": "some example content"
            }
        }
    }
    "Journal": {
        "user": "GAE user object",
        "name": "journal 2",
        "JournalItems": {
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry 1",
                "content": "some example content"
            },
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry 2",
                "content": "some example content"
            },
            "JournalItem": {
                "name": "entry n",
                "content": "some example content"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that wasn't to long-winded to be annoying. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much the way to do it, except I would use a `ListProperty(db.Key)` instead of int. Then you can do `db.get(userjournals.journals)` to get all the user's journals once you have the `Journals` instance belonging to that user (note that to avoid confusion, you should probably call that something like `UserJournals`).

Remember that GAE is a non-relational datastore, and sometimes you have to think a bit differently from how you would using SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know anything about the difference between non-relational databases and relational ones. I read up on them and now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) which describes in an elegant fashion how you can model your entities relationships on Google Appengine.

The reversed approach you can take is to create a reference for example of a Journal in the JournalItem entity and assign a collection_name to it.

```
class JournalItem:
  Journal = db.ReferencePoperty(Journal, collection_name='journal_items')
  name = db....
  content = db...
```

The you will be able to iterate through the JournalItems of the Journal in this fashion:

```
for item in journal.journal_items
  logging.info(item.content)
```